# How do I keep the hostname in the address bar when redirecting to a sub-domain

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting, hosting, rules

I have a website at example.domainA.com, and I'm using Nginx proxy manager to direct traffic from domainB.com to example.domainA.com, this is working fine, however in the address bar the domain changes from domainB.com to example.domainA.com. How do I keep the original domain in the address bar? I'm using nginX

I've tried rewrite rules in .htaccess but its not working.

Comment: You can not make an external redirect then, you will need to proxy the request instead.